# Skip a number in a summation

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} n^2$$

Returns:

> $1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81 + 100$

and I would like it to return:

> $1 + 9 + 25 + 49 + 81 + 121 + 169 + 225 + 289 + 361$

How will I go about this and, more importantly, how does it work?

Comment: $$\sum_{r=0}^9(2r+1)^2$$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{10}(2n-1)^2$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you.

Comment: do you mean how to increment by 2 the summation index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for $1^2 + 3^2 +5^2 +7^2 +9^2 +11^2+13^2+15^2+17^2 +19^2$

so whats wrong with

$$\sum_{n=0}^9(2n+1)^2$$

or

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}(2n-1)^2$$

It's $2n$ because we are going up in twos

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when it is easy, the short way is to transform the radical.
Sometimes it is not possible because the argument would become too complex

There is not something like the *step* of a *loop for ... next*.

```
sum  0
for n = 1 to 10 step 2
    sum += n^2
next
```

A method without introducing a new argument is to qualify the index or to express it through a relation :

$S = \sum_{odd.n=1}^{10} n^2$

$U = \{ 1,3,...,9\}$ , $S = \sum_{n \in U} n^2 $

Comment: The "heavy method" does not seem to produce what is requested.

Comment: Obviously. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did ; edited, hope it's now correct